# Dense subset in product topology

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Suppose $D\subset R^2$ (with the product topology in $R\times R$ ) is dense (in $R$) and also connected. Must $D = R^2$?  Explain with proof or example.

Comment: the plane minus a countable set is connected and dense, e.g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ is countable in the plane, $D=\Bbb R^2\setminus A$ is (path-)connected: there are uncountably many disjoint(-except-endpoints) paths between any two points in $\Bbb R^2$ and removing $A$ can only kill countably many such paths. So $D$ is path-connected.

$D$ is also dense, as any non-empty open set in $\Bbb R^2$ is uncountable, so remains that way (in particular, non-empty) after cutting out $A$.

Comment: Thank you very much for a perfect explanation.

Answer (score 3):

No, let $D$ be the union of all lines $y=kx$ with rational slope $k$.

Comment: Thank you Ding for the answer. But will you please explain a little more about it ? I will really appreciate it.

Comment: In fact this $D$ is path connected: every point in $D$ can be linked by straight line (in $D$) to the origin. And it is dense, for any point $(a, b)$, compute its slope $b/a$ (which may be infinity), then take a sequence of rational numbers $k_n\to b/a$, then the point $(a, k_na)$ on the line $y=k_nx$ converges to $(a, b)$ when $n\to\infty$ (you can modify this a little to treat the $a=0$ case)..

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I liked it.